# Ads purgeIdleCellConnections ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ads, chartboost

This issue just started showing up. I am getting the following when I try to cache [Chartboost](https://chartboost.com/) ads to show later. There is no issue in the simulator but when I try to test on a actual device no ads ever show. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1fd38360
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1fdf5e20
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1fde23d0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1fdc16e0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1fdb5ec0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test Chartboost ads in real device in 2 ways.

« 1. Enable testmod in chartboost App section.

« 2. Add publishing campaign and add your device UDID in test device. See these screenshot for more information.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]